# Facebook like button in plain HTML, is it possible?

Tags: facebook, links, social-media

just a quick question, **is it possible to create an *FB Like* button in plain HTML?**

I checked out the Like button code dircetly cerated by [developers.FB](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) but it's an

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=...></iframe>
```

I also checked out the [addthis.com](http://www.addthis.com/web-button?where=website&type=bm&clickbacks=1&frm=home&bm=tb8&analytics=0) and it's a bunch of **Javascript**.

I mean: **is there a way to just use something simple?** Example:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com...?page=my-fb-page..." rel="nofollow">FB like, click here</a>
```

I know in this way it won't show anymore "how many people like", but I don't mind this, I just want something simple, so I can use my own icon or text, etc.

In my understanding for the Share button is possible by just adding:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=your-percent-encoded-url-of-your-site-page.hmtl">To share on FB click here.</a>
```

So i suppose it could be possible also for the Like button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don’t believe that this can be done. The code for the like button has to determine if you are logged into an account and if so, whether or not you’ve liked the topic already. This couldn’t be done in plain HTML. The closest you could get is the iframe that you mentioned.

Comment: As a long time FB dev, I'm just here to confirm what Adam wrote. There is no way to do this without the `iframe` HTML tag or `fb:like` FBML tag.

Comment: I think you are right I looked in <iframe> source generated by FB, but it's a mess of javascript. I hope to find a simp,e plain HTML link there, but nothing.

Comment: It might be required due to FB's implementation, but neither of the things mentioned here require JavaScript. It could all be done server-side. The only thing you wouldn't be able to do is use AJAX to like the page without reloading or display real-time like counts.

Comment: @Lese majeste: what do you mean server-side?

Comment: Javascript would be considered client side, as it runs on the clients computer. Server side is something like javascript. It runs on the server without anything having to be executed on the client's end.

Comment: @Adam Thompson: thanks I know this! My point was that I don't understand what this has got to do with the question/answer of this page. It's obvious that if you can write a link in plain HTML, you can also write it serve-side using a PHP script, unless Lese means something different.

Comment: Ah, I got you. I think that maybe he's talking about using Facebook's PHP API. Basically you can use what they call the social graph to interact with Facebook. This is all done through PHP code. As bit of an example take a look at the Facebook Developers site: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#personalization

Comment: @Marco: I meant the function of checking if the user is logged in or has voted or not could be done after they click on a plain link. So you could in theory just have a plain HTML link, and let facebook take care of the rest server-side. And the like count could just be a dynamically generated image. Though, I actually hadn't thought of Adam's suggestion of using Facebook's API. If facebook provides no standard way of using a simple link, then maybe a way could be implemented using their API.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm thinking of something like a regular link to a URL like `/like.php?u=[url]`. And when you click on it, it creates a popup window that either asks you to log in or lets you like the page. It would be just like the share button. And you'd also have an image to a url like `/like_count.php?u=[url]` that shows the number of people who've liked that page.

Answer (score 1):

A sort of work around could be to create also a FB page for your website, then you add a small FB icon on your website that links to the FB page. :)

It wouldn't be as trivial for final user as clicking the FB "Like button", cause it would have to visit your FB page and then click the Like button over there.

At least for FB we have this sort of work around, for Google +1 button there seems to be no way other than including their API.

As a side note, I have to say that it's quite irritating to almost be forced to place all these JS code from Google + FB on my pages, they could sniff/track visits and other stuff on my sites, but I suppose we have no more chances to avoid adding such buttons in now days. :(