# Google +1 something via a URL

Tags: google, google-plus-one

Is there a way to +1 something via a URL, just like you would with Twitter or Facebook?

---

e.g.

With Twitter you have:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status={url}
```

With Facebook you have:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&t={title}
```

With Digg you have:

```
http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url={url}&title={title}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to use Facebook "Like" in the same way? If yes you could answer ot my question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6218/facebook-like-button-in-plain-html-is-it-possible

Comment: Sadly, Google are rivalling Apple in control-freakery.

Answer (score 1):

This is new, it was just posted by Google: [Doing more with +1 button](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/doing-more-with-1-button-more-than-4.html):

> beginning today, we're making it easy for Google+ users to share
>   webpages with their circles, directly from the +1 button. Just +1 a
>   page as usual and look for the new "Share on Google+" option.

So how do you do this? Use +Snippets

> When you share content from the +1 button... we automatically include a link, 
>   an image and a description in the sharebox. We call these "+snippets"

The real details are here, on the Google Webmaster Central blog: [making the most of improvements to Google +](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/08/making-most-of-improvements-to-1-button.html).

> The +1 button now lets visitors share links to your pages on Google+.

Example code containing each of the +Snippet attributes:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"> 
<h1 itemprop="name">This is the article name</h1> 
<img itemprop="image" src="thumbnail.jpg" /> 
<p itemprop="description">This is the description of the article.</p> 
</body>
```

The article suggests using what it calls [the configuration tool for +snippets](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) There are several input parameters, but the simplest example was

```
<!-- Update your html tag to include the itemscope and itemtype attributes -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<!-- Add the following three tags inside head -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title Of Your +1 Content">
<meta itemprop="description" content="This would be a description of the content your users are +1ing">
<meta itemprop="image" content="images/cool-image.png">
```

Comment: Interesting, but not quite what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can *share* something via the following URL, [as per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink-endpoint):

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}
```

or alternatively

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?url={url}&title={title}
```

This is the Google+ equivalent to the Facebook and Twitter methods you’ve posted above. Unfortunately, this won’t *+1* the link, only share it. I’m not very clear on the exact difference between these two actions, since the above actually loads a page which says

> You publicly recommended this as {your name here}

– which sounds awfully like +1’ing. However, submitting the page verifiably only shares the link on Google+, it doesn’t add it to the person’s “+1’s”.